# C# WPF Perform action while button down

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I detect that the button in my application is still clicked (down)? and how to know when it is released?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Are you looking for [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.repeatbutton.aspx)? It's one of the built-in WPF button controls, and it raises its Click event repeatedly if you press and hold the button. It's used internally to implement things like the "up-arrow" and "down-arrow" buttons on a scrollbar.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown.aspx) and [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup.aspx) events

Example:

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" Content="Button1" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Same goes for MouseUp

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events.